# Logger that logs to console and file at different levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a bootstrap script for a Raspberry Pi that runs in python. I am looking to create a logger that logs to a file as well as to the console.

I was going to do something like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, fileName)),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ])
```

But what I would really like is to log INFO to the StreamHandler and DEBUG to the FileHandler... I cannot seem to figure that out.

Can anyone help me out?

Using Python 3.7.5

Comment: What does the 12.2s and 5.5s signify in this statement ->       %(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s   ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build the logger yourself (either through a config file or in pure python)

The tricky thing that I have wasted several hours on is forgetting to set the log level on the logger as well as on each of the handlers. Ensure that the logger is as permissive as the most permissive handler.

example script

```
# emits the info line to the console and
# both the info & debug lines to the log file

# test_pylog.py
import logging

log_format = logging.Formatter(
  '%(asctime)s %(threadName)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

logger.addHandler(console_handler)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logfile.txt')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  logger.debug('Panic! at the disco')
  logger.info('Weezer')
```

Comment: Just a small extra to add to this: I always go back to reference [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) doc, which provides some nice extras to keep in mind. Logging for some reason is that thing I always have to go back to when I'm setting it up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Function to return Logger with **individual** **Format** and **Level** for console and file:

```
import logging


def get_my_logger(name: str = __name__):
    """Returns logger with individual Format and Level for console and file"""    
# =============================================================================
#    SET PARAMETERS for Handlers
# =============================================================================
    # Console Log Parameters
    ConsoleLevel = logging.INFO
    ConsoleFormat = '%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)8s:%(funcName)s:%(message)s'
    ConsoleDateFormat = "%H:%M:%S"

    # File Log Parameters
    FileName = 'sample.log'
    FileLevel = logging.DEBUG
    FileFormat = '%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)8s:%(funcName)s:%(message)s'
    FileDateFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

# =============================================================================
#   SET Handlers for logger
# =============================================================================
    # StreamHandler - logging config for console
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    sh.setLevel(ConsoleLevel)
    sh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(ConsoleFormat))
    sh.formatter.datefmt = ConsoleDateFormat

    # FileHandler - logging config for File
    fh = logging.FileHandler(FileName, mode='w')
    fh.setLevel(FileLevel)
    fh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FileFormat))
    fh.formatter.datefmt = FileDateFormat

# =============================================================================
#   SET Logger
# =============================================================================
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    # set handlers
    logger.handlers = [sh, fh]
    # set logger.setLevel as lowest, if handle multiple handlers independently
    logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)   # have higher priority than handlers level

    return logger
```

### NB! Some thoughts...

**1. In log initial setup:**

Instead of:

```
logger.addHandler(sh)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

I prefer     `logger.handlers = [sh, fh]`.
Otherwise you will get duplicated/triplicated/... lines, if not exit the shell (Spyder in my case) after each run (as far as it's don't remove handlers automatically after  execution ).

**2. if handle multiple handlers independently**

set `logger.setLevel` as lowest

```
logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)   # have higher priority than handlers
```

For example, if you set `logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)` (default) and
and DEBUG level for console:

```
sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

you will get on console only WARNING levels and above